# Azure OpenAI Streaming response concept in MS Team Chatbot

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-openai

The streamingAsync concept in Azure Open AI is quite impressive and will likely enhance the user experience in the MS Teams chatbot. Presently, all send activities occur in a single method call within the bot framework.

```
await dialogContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(result);
```

How can we implement [OpenAIClient.GetCompletionsStreamingAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.ai.openai.openaiclient.getcompletionsstreamingasync?view=azure-dotnet-preview#azure-ai-openai-openaiclient-getcompletionsstreamingasync(system-string-azure-ai-openai-completionsoptions-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) concept in the bot framework, because currently only supports posting all messages at once? Most of the Azure OpenAI stream examples use a foreach loop with console output. Is there any existing functionality for this? If not, when can we expect it to be available?

Comment: Please Track this issue from here-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1321104/how-to-integrate-openaiclient-getcompletionsstream

Comment: I have added my comments there - Thank you @Sayali-MSFT

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT are there any updates? looking for ms teams channel samples.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT - are there any updates? still, we are searching for a solution.